# How to accsses these image url inside the map i.e a json file?

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart

[image]

I am  getting this problem to access the URL inside the maps image. what is the syntax to access it?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Maybe because you have not provided extension. Try to add extension like JPG, JPEG or PNG.

Comment: I thing you should show us your code instead. Then it will be easier to see what is wrong.